# Credit card debt someone want to pay off for me

Tags: credit, scams

I am in credit card debt approximately $20,000. I am on a fixed income there is no way I can pay the payments. I recently met someone on a dating site. We have been talking for three weeks. She claims to be a consultant for a crypto project at its ICO stage working currently out of the country. She asked me to check her checking account here in the states. Her balance exceeded ten million. I am broke and on a fixed income. She wants to pay off my credit cards. She asked me to send her the information. All of them are closed or close to it for nonpayment. Is this legitimate or a scam,  I have only a used car which I just purchased and a small IRA. Is it safe for me to accept her offer. She is supposed to return by next week. I will meet her for the first time. is this safe or not. It would really help me my phone rings consistently from debt collectors.

Comment: Here's the stink test: Why would anyone without an agenda want to help you?

Comment: If there's any question, that's a fake banking website.

Comment: Of course it's a scam.  The only question is what sort of scam is it?  My guesses would be either advance fee fraud, or they want you as a mule for money laundering.

Comment: Don't meet her.  Don't talk to her on the phone.  Don't communicate with her in any way.

Comment: If "on fixed income" means that there is no way to earn more, you should reduce the spendings. Or file bankrupcy.

Answer (score 9):

This is a huge scam and con game.  I'm sorry, I know that's a tough pill to swallow because it also means the relationship isn't genuine.

Yes, something is up here.  They either plan to "overpay" you and have you send the excess back to them via an irreversible method like Western Union, iTunes gift cards, Bitcoin etc.....  Or they plan to crank money through your accounts as money laundering, e.g. from other accounts they have hacked.

Typically at some point they disappear, leaving you holding the bag for a check that is no good, or electronic transfer that has been reversed.

**If they *really* want to pay off  your credit card, then take one of the payment coupons from the bottom of a paper bill, make 10 copies of it, and send that to them by postal mail.  They can send a paper check in to the credit card company if they are serious.**   But even this is dangerous; they could *"accidentally overpay"* it and then say "Oh, and please buy these high-value easily fenced things for me and ship them to me".  iPads, leather jackets, etc.  That would be a disaster for you when the payment later bounces.

Comment: Why 10 copies??

Comment: because they are typically are 1/3 page, so ten of them, plus a cover letter, is just under 1 ounce.

Comment: I still don't get it.  Why is it important that the letter weigh just under one ounce?

Comment: because spending  a second ounce stamp on this scam is throwing good money after bad!